# Regular expressions in Ruby with special characters

Tags: ruby, regex, string

In Ruby, how can I split a string such as `"John Doe+123456"` so that I may have two variables with the characters both before and after the `"+"`?

I just started with Ruby today, but I can't seem to get special characters such as `"+"` to cooperate.

As a note, I am not new to programming, just Ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you already know you're always splitting on the same character, you can just provide the character as a string:

```
   > "John Doe+123456".split('+')  # no regular expression needed
   => ["John Doe", "123456"]
```

or if you have to use a regular expression, then escape the `+` with a `\` :

```
   > "John Doe+123456".split(/\+/) # using a regular expression; escape the +
   => ["John Doe", "123456"]
```

last not least, here is another way to do this:

```
   > "John Doe+123456".scan(/[^+]+/) # find all sequences of characters which are not a +
   => ["John Doe", "123456"]
```

Comment: Clarification for the question author: `+` is part of regex syntax, in order to use it literally, as a symbol itself, you should escape it like `\+`. UPD: already there :D

Comment: The last, using `scan` is not a realistic way to process the string since `split('+')` exists and does it more elegantly.

Comment: in this case yes, but I wanted to mention it, because it's good to learn about `scan` when parsing is needed..

Answer (score 3):

Unless you literally mean, the last character of the string before the `+` and the first directly after it, splitting a string in ruby is easy with the `.split` method, which takes the delimiter as its argument.

```
> string = "John Doe+123456"
> string.split('+')
=> ["John Doe", "123456"]
```